# TortoiseGit, configure automatic merge tool on per-file-basis

Tags: git, matlab, simulink, tortoisegit

I am using Msysgit with TortoiseGit to manage repositories containing different file types that need special diff and merge tools, including Matlab Simulink files.

I have configured these tools in TortoiseGit -> Settings -> External Programs -> Diff Viewer / Merge Tool.
Principially, the configuration works.

Now I have encountered the problem, that TortoiseGit tries to merge my Simulink files automatically, using its own merge tool, which results in the error message:

```
"Merge conflict in filename.mdl. Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result."
```

Also, the file TortoiseGit tried to merge is corrupted afterwards. The file is highlighted with an exclamation mark and I can resolve the error with my configured merge tool via the TortoiseGit context menu.

I have worked around the automatic merging problem by specifying

```
*.mdl -merge
```

in my gitattributes file. Now TortoiseGit does no longer try to merge automatically, but I still have to invoke the merge tool via the context menu to fix the conflicts for each .mdl file.

Is there a way to force TortoiseGit to invoke the special .mdl-file merge tool as a replacement for its own automatic merge tool? The configuration must be on a per-filetype-basis.

Comment: An automatically working solution for the terminal would also work when calling Git via TortoiseGit, I believe. But I could not figure out one for that case either.
Eventually, I need to set up a solution that works with TortoiseGit, as I am not in a hacker/computer scientist environment here. The other users where hard to convince that a VCS is a good idea. Convincing them to use the terminal will be impossible.

Comment: i have felt your pain before. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Diff viewer -> Merge. There click on the Advanced button. Here you can configure different merge tools for specific file types.